# Excel formula to calculate average temp for every hour

Tags: excel-formula

Please help to adjust the formula so the results to appear in an adjacent column next end of each hour so I can process the spreadsheet further to get a heatmap. Is there a way that average hour results appear next to corresponding date and hour?

I am using the following formula which however is not perfect as it works on several rows and divide by 0 error apears

```
=AVERAGEIF(C$2:C$81,$B$2:$B$81,">="&$J2,$B$2:$B$81,"<="&$K2)
```

```
Date       Time     Temperature start   end         average hour temp
2022/08/01  0:00:16 15.5       0:00:00  0:59:59    15.48
2022/08/01  0:04:32 15.5       1:00:00  1:59:59    15.46
2022/08/01  0:09:40 15.5       2:00:00  2:59:59    15.28
2022/08/01  0:14:47 15.5       3:00:00  3:59:59    15.04
2022/08/01  0:19:55 15.4       4:00:00  4:59:59    14.59
2022/08/01  0:25:03 15.5       5:00:00  5:59:59    14.09
```

I am sorry, I can not paste excel file. the system does not allow me to embed.

Comment: I believe in your example formula you meant `AVERAGEIFS`, as your have provided 5 arguments.  It’s not clear exactly what you are trying to accomplish.   The way your table is presented make it appear that the rows are related all the way across but is it correct that you actually have about 80 values in columns A:C, and then a separate table of 24 results in J-K-L?  Also, it’s very important to know what version of Excel you are on.  If you have Excel O365 this gets way, way easier.

Comment: I am trying to get an everage temp per each our in a seperate column.  I need these columns: date, time (by hour increment) and avarge temp per each hour. I am using Microsoft 365.